# Fingerprints do not match record?

Tags: papers-please

I'm playing [Papers Please](http://dukope.com/). I see a citizen whose height doesn't match, so I fingerprint him. The name on the fingerprint slip ends up matching the name on the ID card, so I let him through. However, I get a citation anyway - invalid height, and fingerprints records do not match. Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

UPDATE: Ok, it seems that if I have a document from the person with a fingerprint on it, then I can match that with the fingerprint I just got, and this is consistent. If the fingerprints match, I approve, if not, I reject, and it's ok. However, if the person didn't give me their fingerprints, then it seems like a crapshoot. Even if the names match, sometimes I reject and it's ok, other times I reject and it says I should've let them in.

Comment: Did you compare the fingerprints?

Comment: @3ventic: This was before I got the ID cards. However, it just happened again after I got the ID cards. The photo didn't match, but the name and fingerprints all did, yet I still got the citation. Very frustrating! I guess I will just deny people if this happens again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my experience, when there's an option for a fingerprint check you give one sheet to the person and another one is printed for you.

- If height/weight didn't match, it's enough for prints to match and name on the printed sheet should match the one in the papers.
- If names don't match, then prints must match and there should be a second name in the "alias" section of the printed paper.

By the way, appearance of the printed paper with correct name does not mean that fingerprints match. You need to get the sheet from the person and visually compare it to the printed one.

Comment: Ohh of course! I am a horrible inspector. I thought the printed paper was the one with their prints. Thanks sir! I'm going for 100% accuracy, want to see what happens...

Comment: I made the same mistake myself! I also find it quite hard to tell male from female in some cases.

Comment: I always run the discrepancy check between the fingerprints they provide and the printed fingerprints from record (also, on the ID supplement there's a print, I'll check that too just to be sure)